# Save text as html in database

Tags: java, html

I have input field textarea. If i write text in that field that have html tags and save that to database, when i get that data from database it should be processed as html.

Example:

Text in textarea:

```
<html>
    <p>This is <b>example</b>.</p><br>This is second row.
</html>
```

When i get this from database, it should be represented as this:

> This is **example**.
>
> This is second row.

Is it possible to do and if it is how can i do this. Also tags should be case insensitive. For example `<html>` should be same as `<HTML>`.

Comment: Where is an example?

Comment: That's the example :D

Comment: Try to rephrase the question, it's unclear what you want.

Comment: "When i get this from database, it should be represented as this:" ???

Comment: @alonso05. It will print as per your expectation. I think, you didn't even tried once.

Comment: Generally the data you retrieve from the database is the same data you saved to the database.  What have you *actually tried* and what *actual problem* have you encountered?

Comment: @alonso05 I guess you want to save raw html code in DB and retrieve it as rendered by browser. But honestly, I can't not get what you meant by "represented as this". You want to represent it in a String, char array or what ;)

Answer (score 0):

why not use a parser like jsoup to parse the text to html? If I understood right, you want to parse the text and display it like a HTML content?

Answer (score -1):

you have to use `varchar or Text` data type into database and store full text from textarea into database and when yopu retrive data from database use data into `<p> </p>`  tag.

Comment: The `<html>` tag in the example should certainly not be inside of a `<p>...</p>` element.